# boost build - sources with the same name

Tags: filenames, boost-build

```
src
  |--Manager.cpp
  |--Specializations
  |    |--Manager.cpp
```

Building this Boost.Build tries to create

```
/bin/...
  |--Manager.o
  |--Manager.o
```

but fails. How to resolve this automatically? I read [FAQ item](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_50_0/doc/html/bbv2/faq.html#bbv2.faq.duplicate), but I don't like the solution, as I have to fix things manually when I have a same class name, but different namespace. Would it be possible to make Boost.Build automatically prefix object file names with directory?

```
/bin/...
  |--Manager.o
  |--Specializations.Manager.o
```

Or duplicate the source directory tree?

```
/bin/...
  |--Manager.o
  |--Specializations
  |    |--Manager.o
```

Comment: I have a very similar problem: where a project's source codes are in a directory with the same name as the executable target, boost b2 is by default trying to create the executable in the same location as, and with the same name as, the directory tree with the object files in. This is a real pain and I don't have a solution (other than renaming the target, which causes other problems)... E.g. bin/gcc-4.4.7/release/threading-multi contains source-dir-name and therefore target name with same name cant be built.

Comment: @fig it seems to me that the version you get from boost is quite different from the version you get from boost build official pages. For example "boost" version of boost build does not work for me at all now, while "boost build" version of boost build works still fine. The latter also creates a proper directory tree. Go to http://www.boost.org/boost-build2/ and try the version from there. You can easily embedd it to your project (we have it like this). If it doesn't work make a question and notify me here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This behavior has been changed a long time ago and should just work. Boost.Build now mimics the source structure, i.e. you should get both `bin/Manager.o` and `bin/Specializations/Manager.o`.

Comment: This really suprises me. It works on CentOS as you describe, but on my Arch Linux it does not. I just tried with Debian - works as you describe. It seems there is something wrong with Arch...