# boost build: dots in target file name

Tags: filenames, boost-build

Is it possible to have a target which generates file with dots in the filename? I don't need them in target name, just in the filename it produces, so for example

```
lib Auhorization@Plugin : ...
```

would be perfectly fine, if it produces `libAuthorization.Plugin.so` and if I can use it from other targets:

```
exe Application : ... : <library>Authorization@Plugin ...
```

As using dots is the company convention, I cannot just use underscores instead.

One option would be some requirement changing the name of target - like `<name>`.

I also cannot use simple rename post build step, as the Application must be linked to `libAuthorization.Plugin.so`, not `libAuthorization_Plugin.so`. But if something else is possible, I could use it as well.

The build process itself runs under Linux using gcc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For any complex naming schemes you can use the <tag> feature. For your purpose it could look like this:

```
import regex ;
import type ;

rule at-to-dot ( name : type : property-set )
{
    local name = [ regex.replace $(name) @ . ] ;
    local ext = [ type.generated-target-suffix $(type) : $(property-set) ] ;
    return $(name).$(ext) ;
}

lib Auhorization@Plugin : bbb.cpp : <tag>@at-to-dot ;
```

Comment: Could you please tak a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11599986/boost-build-sources-with-the-same-name?rq=1 as well? I browsed boost-build mailing list, found something there, but it was 7 years old and not finished. Right now I am about to write some complex rules to handle it (by naming the object files with paths), but I wonder if there is a more simple way...